# Can I clear available gestures?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna

I've made a small game that uses level, and level is just a int that gets incremented so I use the same class.

Right now I'm just doing some debugging. setting my game to accept tap and hold and in the update i check for `TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable` but regardless of win or loss, the next time i enter the game `TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable` is true :(

This is a silverlight/xna game so i mix the two and the only time i use xna is in the game only. rest of the menu and stuff is xaml.

Any way I can set it to be false, clear the list or something each time i enter this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to clear the gestures buffer on TouchPanel is to call [ReadGesture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.touch.touchpanel.readgesture) till [IsGestureAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.touch.touchpanel.isgestureavailable) returns false. You could do this in your OnNavigatedTo method on your page.

Comment: Ah, i see. Fixed my little problem :D TY